# c++ templates overloading method depend on class type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have class like this:

```
template<typename T>
MyClass{
   //myFunc();
}
```

I want to create myFunc method that return numeric value if class template is numeric and return nothing (void) when class template is not numeric.

For now, I got sth like this:

```
template<typename T>
MyClass{
   template <typename returnT>
   returnT myFunc();
}


template <typename T>
template <typename returnT>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>
T MyClass<T>::myFunc()
{
    return T::value;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename returnT>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>
void MyClass::myFunc()
{
    //do sth
}
```

of course, that doesn't work.  Is that a good idea to solve this problem this way? What is "smart" and working solution?

Comment: Depends, will the two versions of the function differ a lot? `if constexpr` could be a good option if you can use `c++17`.

Comment: Also, using SFINAE in functions like that you need overloaded functions. That means you need two versions of `myFunc` in the class for that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the `constexpr if` solution already supplied, here is your initial idea in it's working form.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyClass{
   template <typename returnT = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<returnT>, bool> = true>
   T myFunc();

   template <typename returnT = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<returnT>, bool> = true>
   void myFunc();
};


template <typename T>
template <typename returnT, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<returnT>, bool>>
T MyClass<T>::myFunc()
{
    std::cout << "yo\n";
    return T{};
}

template <typename T>
template <typename returnT, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<returnT>, bool>>
void MyClass<T>::myFunc()
{
    std::cout << "yay\n";
}

int main() {
    MyClass<int> m;
    MyClass<std::string> n;
    m.myFunc();
    n.myFunc();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  What if i want to use this function like : ```m.myFunc<myType>():``` and then in myFunc: ```return myType::someAtr``` I thought that one more ```template ``` exactly above myFuction is enought, but its not :(

Comment: @ziyiyituxe `m.myFunc<myType>` would reach the `yay` branch since `myType` is not arithmetic. I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you want `MyClass<int>` to always return an `int` even if it's used like `MyClass<int>::myFunc<myType>();`?

Comment: I mean, I want ```myFunc``` to take ```myType``` typename and then, if MyClass is numeric ```return myType::someAtr;``` and if not: ```cout<<"Not numeric";```

Comment: That can be done. If you need all the combinations to work you need to keep adding more overloads. Either way it's probably better if you ask a new question and be more specific if you want a different answer instead of modifying this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of would be to just use `if constexpr`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    auto myFunc()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
        {
            return T{};
        }
        else
        {
            // do smth
        }
    }
};
```

If you can't use C++17, you will have to revert to some SFINAE-based approach. What that would best look like exactly depends a lot on what the actual signatures involved should be. But, for example, you could provide a partial class template specialization for the case of an arithmetic type:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
class MyClass
{
    void myFunc()
    {
        // do smth
    }
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
{
    T myFunc()
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

Note that an arithmetic type cannot be a class type or enum, so I'm not sure what `T::value` was trying to achieve in your example code for the case of `T` being an arithmetic type…

Answer (score 1):

I would create a helper template class to select the return type, and a helper function that uses overloading to perform the right behavior.

```
template <typename, bool> struct RType;
template <typename T> struct RType<T, false> { typedef void type; };
template <typename T> struct RType<T, true> { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
class MyClass{
    typedef RType<T, std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> R;

    void myFuncT(RType<T, false>) {}
    T myFuncT(RType<T, true>) { return 0; }

public:
    typename R::type myFunc() { return myFuncT(R()); }
};
```

Comment: https://tio.run/##lZA7a8MwEIB3/4qDDklKWjrLrpfQQIamxahDoSAUWWkFsmysc4gT8ttdSXHeS@tF1um77x6iqh6@hejulBG6ySUk2FaSYc0V2jQ6hVVpsZa8SDuURaU59qjhhRzDoix1Co5oBEJGXTyObjmgl0xCx7Dk2soUtuChXC5hVao8XGLY/VXirhcOeis4z4@E5tbCazvx5zYC9x1SLeaEKMt4rfCnkKhE4grO4gvoWHhGyIprXzzbE6H7op02RtDh1ZAj12HQi7JBSBJg7D17ofSTTT/mEzp7mzPmw4MvM3C9Bx@9lYVh/@eqJTa1gSdvrZqFVoIc5wk7yQjx/32xobf3Ocfyw9HIp@/iThmEgisDnguefpOJe0lhvd@Ep1p4hvXjQRpfs3CfwmYf3ZxRu@4X